# Eclipse plug-in: How to make a plugin communicate with CDT

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I would like to augment Eclipse CDT with my own plugin, without touching to CDT source file. 
For instance I would like to build a unit test generator wizard.
This wizard has to automatically detect the types of variables tested using the CDT parser.

Does Eclipse CDT provide an API for that?

Is there a documentation for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[here](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp) you can find the CDT Plug-in developer guide. It's a good point to start :)

saluti

Comment: How do you start develop a new stuff that communicate with Eclipse CDT API? http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?nav=/13_1 Is there a pattern to follow to make the plugin use CDT API?

Comment: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/search/searchResults.jsp?searchType=1&searchSite=dW&searchScope=dW&query=cdt%20extension%20example here you can find all the material & examples you need